# LXPanel Volume Control tells me to install alsamixer

Tags: 13.04, lubuntu, alsa, lxde, volume-control

I am using lubuntu 13.04 and out of the blue, the volume control icon that sits in the panel stopped opening alsamixer, when I right-click on it and chose "Volume Control Settings" - it used to open alsamixer.
I can still change volume and mute/unmute when I left-click on the icon.

I can run alsamixer just fine from a terminal.

Can you help me? It's not serious, but annoying ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if xterm is installed, the LXPanel volume control plugin needs it to open alsamixer:

```
sudo apt-get install xterm
```